# Regex for names with special characters (Unicode)

Tags: php, javascript, regex, character-properties

Okay, I have read about regex all day now, and still don't understand it properly. What i'm trying to do is validate a name, but the functions i can find for this on the internet only use `[a-zA-Z]`, leaving characters out that i need to accept to.

I basically need a regex that checks that the name is at least two words, and that it does not contain numbers or special characters like `!"#¤%&/()=...`, however the words can contain characters like æ, é, Â and so on...

An example of an accepted name would be: "John Elkjærd" or "André Svenson"
An non-accepted name would be: "**Hans**", "H**4**nn**3** Andersen" or "Martin Henriksen**!**"

If it matters i use the javascript `.match()` function client side and want to use php's `preg_replace()` only "in negative" server side. (removing non-matching characters).

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Update:**
Okay, thanks to [Alix Axel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963228/regex-for-names-with-special-characters/5963425#5963425) i have the important part down, the server side one.

But as the page from [LightWing's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963228/regex-for-names-with-special-characters/5963334#5963334) suggests, i'm unable to find anything about unicode support for javascript, so i ended up with half a solution for the client side, just checking for at least two words and minimum 5 characters like this:

```
if(name.match(/\S+/g).length >= minWords && name.length >= 5) {
  //valid
}
```

An alternative would be to specify all the unicode characters as suggested in [shifty's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963228/regex-for-names-with-special-characters/5963417#5963417), which i might end up doing something like, along with the solution above, but it is a bit unpractical though.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Try the following regular expression:

```
^(?:[\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}\'\x{2019}]+\s[\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}\'\x{2019}]+\s?)+$
```

In PHP this translates to:

```
if (preg_match('~^(?:[\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}\'\x{2019}]+\s[\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}\'\x{2019}]+\s?)+$~u', $name) > 0)
{
    // valid
}
```

You should read it like this:

```
^   # start of subject
    (?:     # match this:
        [           # match a:
            \p{L}       # Unicode letter, or
            \p{Mn}      # Unicode accents, or
            \p{Pd}      # Unicode hyphens, or
            \'          # single quote, or
            \x{2019}    # single quote (alternative)
        ]+              # one or more times
        \s          # any kind of space
        [               #match a:
            \p{L}       # Unicode letter, or
            \p{Mn}      # Unicode accents, or
            \p{Pd}      # Unicode hyphens, or
            \'          # single quote, or
            \x{2019}    # single quote (alternative)
        ]+              # one or more times
        \s?         # any kind of space (0 or more times)
    )+      # one or more times
$   # end of subject
```

I honestly don't know how to port this to Javascript, I'm not even sure Javascript supports Unicode properties but in PHP PCRE this [seems to work flawlessly @ IDEOne.com](http://www.ideone.com/eNQPq):

```
$names = array
(
    'Alix',
    'André Svenson',
    'H4nn3 Andersen',
    'Hans',
    'John Elkjærd',
    'Kristoffer la Cour',
    'Marco d\'Almeida',
    'Martin Henriksen!',
);

foreach ($names as $name)
{
    echo sprintf('%s is %s' . "\n", $name, (preg_match('~^(?:[\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}\'\x{2019}]+\s[\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}\'\x{2019}]+\s?)+$~u', $name) > 0) ? 'valid' : 'invalid');
}
```

I'm sorry I can't help you regarding the Javascript part but probably someone here will.

---

**Validates**:

- John Elkjærd
- André Svenson
- Marco d'Almeida
- Kristoffer la Cour

**Invalidates**:

- Hans
- H4nn3 Andersen
- Martin Henriksen!

---

To replace invalid characters, though I'm not sure why you need this, you just need to change it slightly:

```
$name = preg_replace('~[^\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}\'\x{2019}\s]~u', '$1', $name);
```

Examples:

- H4nn3 Andersen **->** Hnn Andersen
- Martin Henriksen! **->** Martin Henriksen

Note that you always need to use the *u* modifier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is perfect! i only need to make it work with js now, but it cant be to hard, now i at least have something to go from. :) Ohh, and the reason why i want to remove invalid characters is to avoid something like "Tamperdata" or "cURL" to give me wrong input, but if i validate as well i guess there's no meaning it :) Again, thanks.

Comment: @Kristoffer: I've updated my question to better explain the regex, if no other JS alternative presents you can always use Ajax and call PHP to validate it.

Comment: the explanation of the parts of the regex is great, gives me more than just a blind copy-paste to go for. JS is still giving me trouble, but when/if i find a solution i'll post it here to.

Comment: no great solution for JS was found, but i ended up doing as described in my update of the question.

Comment: @AlixAxel. As off 11 March 2019, js is still Unicode stupid among browsers. As you suggest, use AJAX if wanting to validate as you go, otherwise use the `pattern` attribute to reject main unwanted codes, then fully validate at server.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding JavaScript it is more tricky, since JavaScript Regex syntax doesn't support unicode character properties. A pragmatic solution would be to match letters like this:

```
[a-zA-Z\xC0-\uFFFF]
```

This allows letters in all languages and excludes numbers and all the special (non-letter) characters commonly found on keyboards. It is imperfect because it also allows unicode special symbols which are not letters, e.g. emoticons, snowman and so on. However, since these symbols are typically not available on keyboards I don't think they will be entered by accident. So depending on your requirements it may be an acceptable solution.

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for this because the RegEx above does not work on client side JavaScript validation... I ended up with this: public const string NameFull = @"^(?!.{52,})[a-zA-Z\xC0-\uFFFF\.\'\-]{2,50}(?: [a-zA-Z\xC0-\uFFFF\.\'\-]{2,50})+$"; and validating for Emoji afterwards: https://regex101.com/r/jP5jC5/2

Answer (score 3):

visit this page [Unicode Characters in Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Answer (score 2):

you can add the allowed special chars to the regex.

example:

```
[a-zA-ZßöäüÖÄÜæé]+
```

EDIT:

not the best solution, but this would give a result if there are at least to words.

```
[a-zA-ZßöäüÖÄÜæé]+\s[a-zA-ZßöäüÖÄÜæé]+
```

Comment: Why `[ \t]` and not just `\s`?

Comment: @Alis: \s is better. thanks for advice. I'm not a regexpert :D

Answer (score 2):

Here's an optimization over the fantastic answer by @Alix above. It removes the need to define the character class twice, and allows for easier definition of any number of required words.

```
^(?:[\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}\'\x{2019}]+(?:$|\s+)){2,}$
```

It can be broken down as follows:

```
^         # start
  (?:       # non-capturing group
    [         # match a:
      \p{L}     # Unicode letter, or
      \p{Mn}    # Unicode accents, or
      \p{Pd}    # Unicode hyphens, or
      \'        # single quote, or
      \x{2019}  # single quote (alternative)
    ]+        # one or more times
    (?:       # non-capturing group
      $         # either end-of-string
    |         # or
      \s+       # one or more spaces
    )         # end of group
  ){2,}     # two or more times
$         # end-of-string
```

Essentially, it is saying to find a word as defined by the character class, then either find one or more spaces or an end of a line. The `{2,}` at the end tells it that a minimum of two words must be found for a match to succeed. This ensures the OP's "Hans" example will not match.

---

Lastly, since I found this question while looking for a similar solution for [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby), here is the regular expression as can be used in Ruby 1.9+

```
\A(?:[\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}\'\U+2019]+(?:\Z|\s+)){2,}\Z
```

The primary changes are using \A and \Z for beginning and end of string (instead of line) and Ruby's Unicode character notation.

Answer (score 0):

When checking your input string you could

- trim() it to remove leading/trailing whitespaces
- match against [^\w\s] to detect non-word\non-whitespace characters
- match against \s+ to get the number of word separators which equals to number of words + 1.

However I'm not sure that the \w shorthand includes accented characters, but it should fall into "word characters" category.

Comment: `\w` is equivalent to `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`, depending on the specific machine locale this might (not) work with accented / unicode characters, either way it will always match digits, and it shouldn't.

Comment: oh, seems like i'll have to go fix many chunks of my own code then :( thx for valuable info!

Answer (score 0):

This is the JS regex that I use for fancy names composed with max 3 words (1 to 60 chars), separated by space/single quote/minus sign

```
^([a-zA-Z\xC0-\uFFFF]{1,60}[ \-\']{0,1}){1,3}$
```