# preg_match Letters Not only letters?

Tags: php, preg-match

I have looked all around here and online for a solution to this.

The problem is I only want to acceppt letters only. However, if I enter as least one letter, no matter if there are symbols or numbers, then it'll take it. How do I get **only** letters?

```
if (!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]/", $_POST["firstname"]))
    $error = "<br />PLease enter a valid first name";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check a form POST only contains letters on multiple fields using preg\_match?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828684/how-can-i-check-a-form-post-only-contains-letters-on-multiple-fields-using-preg)

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work, that is why I asked. That one still lets me type in numbers and accepts

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/` instead of `/[a-zA-Z]/`:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+$/", $_POST["firstname"]))
    $error = "<br />PLease enter a valid first name";
```

Explanation of the regexp:

- `^` – To match start of the string.
- `[]` – Matches the allowed characters.
- `+` – To match one or more characters of the same type.
- `$` – To match end of string.

Answer (score 1):

In order to deal with unicode, you would use:

```
if (!preg_match("/^[- '\p{L}]+$/u", $_POST["firstname"]))
    $error = "<br />PLease enter a valid first name";
```

I've added the `/u` modifier for unicode and characters `- '` for matching firstname like `Jean-François`

Answer (score 0):

**Anchor** your match. See this code:

```
if ( !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]+$/", $_POST["firstname"]))
    $error = "<br />PLease enter a valid first name";
```

- `^` and `$` asserts thes tart and end of the match.

PS You may have misspelled  "Please" in your code  - "L" is in caps.

Answer (score -2):

Well, I'm not a regex expert but you can just create a function that will check precisely what you need. It'd go somewhere along those lines (that function only checks for lower cases though):

```
$w = "hereisastr";
$i = 0;
while (isset($w[$i]))
{
  if ($w[$i] >= 'a' && $w[$i] <= 'z')
  {
    $i++;
  } else
  {
    return false;
    break;
  }
  return true;
}
```