# preg_match unicode does not work with some languages

Tags: php, regex, unicode, internationalization

With this regular expression can not validate the text in the following languages​​:

```
/^[\p{L}\p{Nd}-_.]{1,20}$/u
```

Languages ​​that do not work:

```
Bengali, Gujarati, Hindi, Marathi, Thai, Tamil, Telugu, Vietnamese
```

when used with PHP's `preg_match`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why those spaces in regex? If that's for readability purpose, use an `/x` modifier.

Comment: @RohitJain: Even that wouldn't work if he puts spaces between the backslash and `p` etc.

Comment: @TimPietzcker. Ah! Of course. Missed that.

Comment: Possible duplicate / Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963228/regex-for-names-with-special-characters-unicode

Answer (score 4):

You're using the dash incorrectly. If you want it to match a literal dash character, you need to either escape it (`\-`) or put it at the end of the character class.

Also, I'm not familiar with those languages, but I guess you might need to account for marks as well:

```
/^[\p{L}\p{Nd}\p{M}_.-]{1,20}$/u
```

Comment: this is solution and you can find more details on http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't come from your regex (except the fact that the character `-` must be always at the begining or at the end of a character class) . Note that your pattern can be shorten as:

```
/^[\w.-]{1,20}$/u
```

or

```
/^[\p{Xan}.-]{1,20}$/u
```

if you want to remove the underscore

Comment: In PHP, even if you use the `/u` option, `\w` only matches `[A-Za-z0-9_]`.  If you want it to match the same as `[\p{L}\p{Nd}_]`, you have to start the regex with `(*UCP)`, forcing it to match by Unicode properties instead of lookup tables:  `/(*UCP)^[\w.-]{1,20}$/u`.  The same applies to `\d`, `\s`, `\b`, and the opposites: `\W`, `\D`, `\S` and `\B`.