# Remove illegal chars from multilanguage string

Tags: php, regex

How can I remove illegal chars from multilanguage string, such as <>'"?* etc.?

I can't just use

```
$allow = "/[^abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-]+/";
$q = preg_replace($allow, "", $q);
```

I need this to use on a full name field with multilanguage support.

Comment: simply, its their name, let them type anything they want - it will do NO harm

Comment: a usefull read: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: Fun read :) Maybe you are right it's 3am shouldn't be coding now...

Comment: programmers tend to be control freaks.

Comment: Your notion of "illegal character" is very naive and broad: are characters like `œ` or `é` allowed? And what is your general goal, why are you trying to forbid characters?

Comment: he or she seems to be wanting to exclude non alphabetical characters (<>'"?* are not likely to appear in names in any language). does php have a unicode alphabetic character class?

Comment: remember little Bobby tables http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: @1010: That shouldn't even be a problem when you use prepare statement. It's generally a warning against string concatenation and poor input sanitization when building an SQL query.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte so names are really names and not like ahm@t, X's pet, "Mike N.", <Mike N.> ........ œ or é  etc. of course allowed

Comment: I think here you'll find what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963228/regex-for-names-with-special-characters-unicode. however beware that X's pet could be a name in some language you don't know...